# tag for collection questions ?

Tags: discussion, tags

We are in the process of opening a lot of questions to collect pre-made ideas, artifacts, spells and so on. Would it make sense to have a common agreed tag for this kind of questions (such as "common" or "collection")? propose a better one.

**Edit** :  I will take the task of tagging the current questions with the new tag.

Comment: What's the "pass" criterion? How many votes do we need to move forward on this? The longer we wait the bigger the task of sorting through questions and tagging them gets.

Comment: @Richard : I don't know, but you are right. Let's close the issue. I'll start tagging tomorrow morning.

Comment: Please note this kind of question has been established as off topic: [Are list/collection questions on topic?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176/are-list-collection-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [reference]?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this makes sense; I also think these kinds of questions should be CW. Although, maybe 'list' is easier than collection?